# How to use grep/sed/awk, to remove a pattern from beginning of a text file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, text-files

I have a text file with the following pattern written to it:

```
TIME[32.468ms]  -(3)-............."TEXT I WANT TO KEEP"
```

I would like to discard the first part of each line containing

```
TIME[32.468ms]  -(3)-.............
```

To test the regular expression I've tried the following:

```
cat myfile.txt | egrep "^TIME\[.*\]\s\s\-\(3\)\-\.+"
```

This identifies correctly the lines I want. Now, to delete the pattern I've tried:

```
cat myfile.txt | sed s/"^TIME\[.*\]\s\s\-\(3\)\-\.+"//
```

but it just seems to be doing the `cat`, since it shows the content of the complete file and no substitution happens.

What am I doing wrong?

OS: CentOS 7

Comment: Tangentially, [the`cat`s are useless.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `grep` command. Written and tested with GNU `grep`.

```
grep -oP '^TIME\[\d+\.\d+ms\]\s+-\(\d+\)-\.+\K.*' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
^TIME\[          ##Matching string TIME from starting of value here.
\d+\.\d+ms\]     ##Matching digits(1 or more occurrences) followed by dot digits(1 or more occurrences) followed by ms ] here.
\s+-\(\d+\)-\.+  ##Matching spaces91 or more occurrences) followed by - digits(1 or more occurrences) - and 1 or more dots.
\K               ##Using \K option of GNU grep to make sure previous match is found in line but don't consider it in printing, print next matched regex part only.
.*               ##to match till end of the value.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding `awk` program here.

```
awk 'match($0,/^TIME\[[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ms\][[:space:]]+-\([0-9]+\)-\.+/){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** using `match` function of `awk`, to match regex `^TIME\[[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ms\][[:space:]]+-\([0-9]+\)-\.+` which will catch text which we actually want to remove from lines. Then printing rest of the text apart from matched one which is actually required by OP.

Comment: `grep -P` is commonly available on Linux, but not standard. The OP have not revealed which OS they are on.

Comment: @tripleee, yeah, I had mentioned its GNU `grep` and added an `awk` solution as well in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working.
If I have TIME as a first word but, as well, TIM it will get TIM instead.

ex
TIME and the rest
TIM and the rest

Comment: @PedroCardoso, both of my codes are working with your shown samples. Is your actual file is same as shown samples?

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` using its `sub()` function:

```
awk 'sub(/^TIME[[][^]]*].*\.+/,"")' file
"TEXT I WANT TO KEEP"
```

- If there is replacement, `sub()` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cut -d'"' -f2 file
TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```sh
s='TIME[32.468ms]  -(3)-............."TEXT I WANT TO KEEP"'
sed -E 's/^TIME\[[^]]*].*\.+//'

"TEXT I WANT TO KEEP"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\s` regex extension may not be supported by your `sed`.

In BRE syntax (which is what `sed` speaks out of the box) you do not backslash round parentheses - doing that turns them into regex metacharacters which do not match themselves, somewhat unintuitively.  Also, `+` is just a regular character in BRE, not a repetition operator (though you can turn it into one by similarly backslashing it: `\+`).

You can try adding an `-E` option to switch from BRE syntax to the perhaps more familiar ERE syntax, but that still won't enable Perl regex extensions, which are not part of ERE syntax, either.

```sh
sed 's/^TIME\[[^][]*\][[:space:]][[:space:]]-(3)-\.*//' myfile.txt
```

should work on any reasonably POSIX `sed`. (Notice also how the minus character does not need to be backslash-escaped, though doing so is harmless *per se.* Furthermore, I tightened up the regex for the square brackets, to prevent the "match anything" regex you had `.*` from "escaping" past the closing square bracket. In some more detail, `[^][]` is a negated character class which matches any character which isn't (a newline or) `]` or `[`; they have to be specified exactly in this order to avoid ambiguity in the character class definition. Finally, notice also how the entire `sed` script should normally be quoted in single quotes, unless you have specific reasons to use different quoting.)

If you have `sed -E` or `sed -r` you can use `+` instead of `*` but then this complicates the overall regex, so I won't suggest that here.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler one for `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^"]*//' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "text you want to keep" always surrounded by the quote like this and only them having the quote in the line starting with "TIME...", then:

```
sed -n '/^TIME/p' file | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

should get the line starting with "TIME..." and print the text within the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, for your help.
By the end, I've found a way to make it work:

`echo 'TIME[32.468ms]  -(3)-.............TEXT I WANT TO KEEP' | grep TIME | sed -r 's/^TIME\[[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ms\]\s\s-\(3\)-\.+//'`

More generally,

`grep TIME myfile.txt | sed -r ‘s/^TIME\[[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ms\]\s\s-\(3\)-\.+//’`
Cheers,
Pedro